# FD-SCAN algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

My professor asked me to implement FD-Scan disc scheduling algorithm. However, I can't find any informations about this in the Internet. How does this algorithm work? Or maybe my professor has misspelled something?

Comment: Feasible Deadline Scan, literally found it within 3 seconds by Googling... It's not my expertise so I can't really help you with an algorithm but there is some info on the web, like [this](https://www.ijltemas.in/DigitalLibrary/Vol.2Issue3/112-120.pdf)

Comment: thanks, I didnt know the full name

Comment: Me neither :p have to admit there's not that much to find, good luck